# Regex to match integers and fractions from input (without matching int twice)

Tags: regex

Looking for a regex in C++ that would add integers and fractions on their own to the regex iterator.

So say we have the current string given

```
12, 144, 18, 12/13, 92, a, 34, 8, 52
```

I'm looking to have `12 144 12/13` all added, without the comma or 12 added twice (or 13)

Currently have `\d+?/\d+|\d+[^/]`

however this also grabs anything after an integer (i.e. the comma)

What am I missing here to make sure I grab the int and not the comma whilst making sure I don't grab numbers from fractions twice?

Comment: Try [`\d+(?:/\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/HT6DTE/3)

Comment: Less efficient, but you could also remove `[^/]` because that matches a comma as well https://regex101.com/r/1zDHfc/1

Comment: [Just get numbers and slashes](https://regex101.com/r/7aNtoS/1) separated by anything else: `[\d\/]+`